# Got user input from a for loop in a JUnit test, now how to actually test its output?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit

So suppose I have the following class with methodA():

```
public class example {

public void methodA() {
    System.out.println("Enter in an integer for each step.\n");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
    int currentStepCount = 0; 
    int totalStepCount = 0;

    for (int step = 10; step <= 16; step++) {
        if (step == 15)
            continue; // Skip fifteenth step

        System.out.println("\nStep " + step + ": ");
        currentStepCount = scan.nextInt();

        totalStepCount += currentStepCount;
    }

    System.out.println("\n\nAll steps have been taken in.\n");
    System.out.println("Total step count comes out to: " + totalStepCount + "\n"); 
    System.out.println("The last step count was " + currentStepCount + ". \n");
}
}
```

And I have a JUnit test that's able to simulate the input:

```
class junitTests {
private final ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

@Before
public void setUpStreams() {
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(output));
}
@Test
void testA() {
    example ex = new example();
    ByteArrayInputStream in1 = new ByteArrayInputStream("13\n13\n13\n13\n13\n13\n".getBytes());

    System.setIn(in1);
    ex.methodA();
    String out = output.toString(); 

    System.out.println(out); //This isn't in the final unit test implementation, 
                            //just for demonstrating my issue.
}
}
```

but I'm stuck on how to actually test whether the output is the correct output. When I try to print `ByteArrayOutputStream output` it comes out as empty so when I try to do an `assertEquals` method, it always fails. How can actually make it so that output is not always empty. Or, more generally, how can I actually test the output of the method altogether. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last `System.out.println` is still using your replaced `PrintStream`, so your output byte array contains two copies. You could store the original `System.out` and use that to print to the console.

```java
    private final ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    private final PrintStream stdout = System.out;
    private final InputStream stdin = System.in;

    @Before
    public void setUpStreams() {
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(output));
    }

    @After
    public void restoreStreams() {
        System.setIn(stdin);
        System.setOut(stdout);
    }

    @Test
    public void testA() {
        example ex = new example();
        ByteArrayInputStream in1 = new ByteArrayInputStream("13\n13\n13\n13\n13\n13\n".getBytes());
        System.setIn(in1);
        ex.methodA();
        String out = output.toString();
        stdout.println(out);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this gives me a `NullPointerException` at the line `stdout.println(out)`. When I comment it out, it works fine otherwise.

Comment: Did you put `stdout = System.out` in `setUpStreams()`?

Comment: Yup. I did pretty much word for word what you did. Does it work when you do it?

Comment: Yes, works for me. Can you check if `System.out` is not null at that point? And that you are running as unit test so that `@Before` is called before the test?

Comment: I modified the code to initialize `stdout/stdin` on instantiation - this may work better for you

Comment: So I edited it so it checks `if (stdout != null)` and if thats false, then it prints `stdout.println(out);` and this time it didn't seem to give me an exception. So I think it is null. And to answer your question, I right-click on the junit test file and run it as a junit test.

Comment: Ok so with your updated code, it ran nicely but nothing printed after the input. So I tried putting it just "Hi" and that seemed to print fine. So my `String out = output.toString()` is an empty string for some reason.

Comment: So it sounds like the other code is affecting the results - can you add more of your code to the question?

Comment: You're gonna think I'm crazy but that is all my code. I even created a brand new java project with only this class and this test cases you provided and string out still ends up coming out to null.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a JUnit test, you should test the output by making some assertion about it; e.g.

```java
assertTrue(output.contains("Total step count comes out to: 15"));
```

if 15 is the correct result. However, this is a bad way of writing a test, because if it fails then you don't know what the actual step count was (instead of 15).

Better to write your method in a way which returns the step count (or whatever you want to test), and then use `assertEquals` to make the assertion about its value. This way you won't need to redirect System.out to test the results. Better still, write your method to take the numbers from an array so you don't need to redirect System.in either.

That said, if you just want to see the printed output of the method then why bother redirecting System.out in the first place? You could just let the method print what it prints.

Comment: For that assertTrue, when I use it, it comes out to false even though the output in the console shows "Total step count comes out to: 78".

Comment: You could combine them with `&&`, but it's better to make separate assetions, because then at least you know *which* one failed, even if you don't know how it failed.

Comment: As for 15 vs. 78, I just used 15 (and said "if 15 is the correct result") because I had no idea what number you actually expected there. You should write 78 in your assertion if that is the correct result.

Comment: Yeah 78 was what I was expecting but it still came out to false. When I try that assertTrue statement with a blank string `""`, that's the only time it comes out to true. Even if I put something like "Step" in there, it's still false.

Comment: You possibly need to do `out.flush();` before `out.toString()` - does that change anything?

Comment: That didn't seem to change anything either. I think the `string out = output.toString()` is empty every time.

Comment: Oh, you need to call `flush()` on the `PrintStream`, I think. You'll need a separate variable to hold a reference to this.

Comment: I added a new variable called `PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(System.out);` and then right after I called `ps.flush()` but that didn't seem to change anything either.

Comment: No, you need to flush the PrintStream that you use in the `System.setOut(...)` call.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best long term solution to the problem is to use dependency injection. boot-and-bonnet is right that you aren't seeing the output because you overwrote the System.out stream. 
What you could do to avoid the need to override the System.out stream is to modify the method so you can pass in a stream you can write to.

```
public static void methodA(PrintStream out) {
    out.println("Enter in an integer for each step.\n");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int currentStepCount = 0;
    int totalStepCount = 0;

    for (int step = 10; step <= 16; step++) {
        if (step == 15)
            continue; // Skip fifteenth step

        out.println("\nStep " + step + ": ");
        currentStepCount = scan.nextInt();

        totalStepCount += currentStepCount;
    }

    out.println("\n\nAll steps have been taken in.\n");
    out.println("Total step count comes out to: " + totalStepCount + "\n");
    out.println("The last step count was " + currentStepCount + ". \n");
}
```

Then you call methodA like this

```
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(output);
methodA(out);
```

And now you can do this

```
System.out.println(output.toString());
```

You can also run any assertions you need on that ByteArrayOutputStream.

Finally, in your code when you run the method outside a unit test you would call it like this

```
methodA(System.out);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! Same thing here happens to me like with boot-and-bonnet's code. `output.toString()` is null for some reason.

Comment: @JustWorkAlready Did you pass the variable out that I declared above into methodA?